# Pandas wide_to_long behaves very differently against the previous version in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I upgraded my laptop and installed Python 2.7 with Pandas 0.23. All my previously working scripts do not run anymore because of wide_to_long different results.

The data frame looks like:

```
Index    ID     Text_column     abc_A   abc_B   abc_C   abc_D
0       123     some text       True    False   False   True
1       124     another text    False   True    False   False
2       125     different topic False   True    True    False
3       126     set of words    False   False   False   False
```

Using the following code:

```
    df2=pd.wide_to_long(df1,['abc_'], i='ID', j='Concept').reset_index()
```

used to give me the following dataframe d2:

```
Index    ID     Concept Text_column     abc_
0        123     A      some text       True
1        123     B      some text       False
2        123     C      some text       False
3        123     D      some text       True
4        124     A      another text    False
5        124     B      another text    True
6        124     C      another text    False
7        124     D      another text    False
8        125     A      different topic False
9        125     B      different topic True
10       125     C      different topic True
11       125     D      different topic False
12       126     A      set of words    False
13       126     B      set of words    False
14       126     C      set of words    False
15       126     D      set of words    False
```

With the version 0.23 I get completely empty data frame like:

```
Index ID  Concept Text_column abc_A abc_B abc_C abc_D
```

I tried melt, but I don't want to specify all columns like [abc_A, abc_B etc.] in value_vars as the variable names are very different for different projects and I have many scripts like that.

What would be the best fix for this issue?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `suffix='\w+'` the default is `suffix='\d+'` which is number

```
pd.wide_to_long(df, ['abc_'], i='ID', j='Concept',suffix='\w+').reset_index()
Out[243]: 
     ID Concept  Index     Text_column   abc_
0   123       A      0        sometext   True
1   124       A      1     anothertext  False
2   125       A      2  differenttopic  False
3   126       A      3      setofwords  False
4   123       B      0        sometext  False
5   124       B      1     anothertext   True
6   125       B      2  differenttopic   True
7   126       B      3      setofwords  False
8   123       C      0        sometext  False
9   124       C      1     anothertext  False
10  125       C      2  differenttopic   True
11  126       C      3      setofwords  False
12  123       D      0        sometext   True
13  124       D      1     anothertext  False
14  125       D      2  differenttopic  False
15  126       D      3      setofwords  False
```

Comment: @ibarant your sample can not reproduced your problem

Comment: Could you please explain what "\w+ " does?

Comment: @ibarant get all alpha which is A-Z